Vite server does not load any pages
I working on a React+Vite project, and over night, the Vite server does not load any pages anymore. After I run npm run dev, I try to visit http://localhost:5173/ but nothing ever loads, no matter what browser I try. I mean there is not even a blank page to right click on to open the console. When opening the console with F12, it is completely empty.
My terminal looks like this:
Terminal with Vite running
I'm not sure what more information to include in this post, other than that everything is working as usual for my team mates.
I tried to solve the problem by re-running npm install, and by cloning the project again, but to no avail.
I also tried to run everything in a Docker container on a remote server I have access to, but I get the same error.

did you check console and network tab on localhost:5173?

When opening the network tab, it prompts me to: "• Perform a request or [Reload] the page to see detailed information about network activity.", other than that, it is empty.
When reloading I get one line:
| - | GET | localhost:5173 | / | document | - | - | - |
Clicking this row gives me:
"No headers for this request".
